# Finding the InverseFunction of a polynomial function restricted to an interval

Tags: polynomials, inverse

I want to calculate the inverse of

```
f[x_] := 1/2 - (x (4 x^2 - 9))/12 /; -1/2 <= x <= 1/2
```

`f[x]` is monotonic inside $-0.5 < x <= 0.5$, but I don't know how to calculate its inverse.

Comment: [does it help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306450/how-do-i-get-the-inverse-of-a-function)

Comment: This is answered in the documentation for [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseFunction.html#87576981)

Answer (score 0):

The inverse you are looking for seems to be

```
invF3[c_] := (3^(2/3)*(1 - I*Sqrt[3]))/
    (4*(-2 + 4*c + Sqrt[1 - 16*c + 16*c^2])^(1/3)) + 
   (1/4)*3^(1/3)*(1 + I*Sqrt[3])*(-2 + 4*c + Sqrt[1 - 16*c + 16*c^2])^(1/3)
```

You can figure this out by doing

```
Solve[c == 1/2 - (x (4 x^2 - 9))/12, x]
```

and then trying out the solutions. Anyway we have

```
invF3[f[1/4]] // FullSimplify
invF3[f[0]] // Simplify
f[invF3@0] // Simplify
```

> 1/4 
>   0 
>   0